# How can I assign a World.createBody to a variable after initialization, `var` and `val` don't work?

Tags: libgdx, box2d, kotlin

```
Class entity() 
{ // there is obviously more code but i dont think if adding them will help 
    val bodyInTheWorld: Body? = null // nulls mean that it will be initialised later, obviously
}
```

I need to set it to null because I need to do a

```
createThis.bodyInTheWorld = world!!.createBody(createThis.body)
```

in main.kt. And that I don't have access to the world object of the main class inside my entity.kt class

```
class main : ApplicationAdapter() {
    private var batch: SpriteBatch? = null
    private var image: Texture? = null
    private var player: entity? = null
    private var camera: OrthographicCamera? = null
    private var world: World? = null
    private val entities = mutableListOf<entity>()

    fun createObject(createThis: entity) // will create reference or copy issues probably...
    {
        if(!entities.contains(createThis))
                entities.add(createThis)
        createThis.bodyInTheWorld = world!!.createBody(createThis.body)
        var temporaryShape = PolygonShape()
        temporaryShape.setAsBox(50f, 1f)
        createThis.bodyInTheWorld.createFixture(temporaryShape, 1f)
    }
```

I was about to write more code but I couldn't fix this damn thing: if I set it to `var` the last line will tell me that it requires an immutable argument.

> *Smart cast to 'Body!' is impossible, because 'createThis.bodyInTheWorld' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time*

And if I set it to `val`, the code doesn't let me do the main thing I want, which is to make that body exist in the world.

```
        createThis.bodyInTheWorld = world!!.createBody(createThis.body)
```

This time the problem is, by syntax and complexity, more reasonable at least, it tells me that I can only define `bodyInTheWorld` variable only once and that I already did that by setting it to null in entity.kt

I need help on this. [This](https://www.gamedevelopment.blog/full-libgdx-game-tutorial-box2d/) is the guide I used to implement box2d btw

Answer (score 0):

Well, so i added a double exclamation mark to the end of the createThis.bodyInTheWorld `createThis.bodyInTheWorld!!.createFixture(temporaryShape, 1f)` and everything suddenly started to work, i still have no idea how it works at all, anyone care to explain?

Comment: i guess mutability has something to do with nulls and this somehow fixes it